# Laravel 8.75 How to get current guard?

Tags: laravel

app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
In old version, it's

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
```

Now it's

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
```

And inside the function, do foreach ($guards as $guard) { ...
But I have frontend and admin(backend), both exists at the same time.

For example, an admin has already logged in both front and admin. When he visits
http://xxx/login => http://xxx/home
http://xxx/admin/login => http://xxx/admin/dashboard

But now larvel 8 uses guards, not guard, so in the foreach, I cannot controller the redirect. What happened is:

A person logged in both frontend web guard and backend admin guard.
Accidentally visits frontend login page, he should be redirected to frontend home page, but because in the foreach loop, admin guard also existed, so he is redirected to admin dashboard.

Comment: This should not really change anything for you. The middleware can accept more than one guard but you don't need to pass more than one guard.

Comment: It really affects. I added some content in the main question.

Comment: In previous version of Laravel you had middleware like `'guest:myguard'` which was the only guard set. In newer versions of Laravel this should result in an array of a single guard so it should behave identically like before. If you add more entries to the guard e.g. `guest:myguard,myotherguard` then you are changing the previous behaviour on purpose. If you don't specify a guard at all then it should only use the default guard. The boilerplate redirect location is constant and doesn't vary by guard. You can always change that yourself in the middleware